# Symfony 3, add a json config file needed by a javascript script managed by assetic

Tags: javascript, json, symfony, assetic

From my symfony website, I want use [particles.js](http://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/) library. I added the library in the directory "particles.js" in /var/www/mywebsite/wev/library. I add mains needed files in assetic ilke that :

```
assetic:
    debug:          '%kernel.debug%'
    use_controller: '%kernel.debug%'
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        scssphp:
            formatter: 'Leafo\ScssPhp\Formatter\Compressed'
    assets:
        particles_css:
            inputs:
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/../web/library/particles.js/particles.css'
        particles_js:
            inputs:
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/../web/library/particles.js/library.js'
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/../web/library/particles.js/run.js'
```

But the particles.js script needs to read a json config file named "particles.json" (also located in /var/www/mywebsite/wev/library ). How can I add this json file in symfony/assetic configuration ?

With my current configuration, when I load my index page, I get this error :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depending on static/dynamic file generation of `particles.json` you can either:

### Statically add particles.json

```yaml
# assetic configuration yaml

assetic:
    assets:
        particles_json:
            inputs:
                - path/to/particels.json
```

And in your template:

```
# template
{% javascripts '@particles_json*' output='particles.json' %}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

This way, Assetic will dump this file at `path/to/project/web/particles.json`.
But it would be much simpler to just add it manually to `/web/particles.json` and forget about the assetic configuration as long as you need it separated from other javascript files.

### Dynamic particles.json

The second way would be bypassing Assetic completely and built your own controller handling this route:

```php
# AppBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php

/**
 * @Route('/particles.json')
 */
public function particlesAction()
{
    $particles = array(); // built your particles here
    return new JsonResponse($particles);
}
```